# How to remove white spaces in a path?

Tags: php, css, image, background-image

I have this style code to display the background image. I tried trim() and urlencode() to remove spaces but didn't work.

```
$get_active_quiz = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE status ='active' AND title = '$title'");
$row_active_quiz = mysql_fetch_array($get_active_quiz);
$background_image = $row_active_quiz['cover_image'];

<body style="
background-image: url(<?php echo $background_image ?>);
background-size:100% auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: What does _didn't work_ mean?, do you get an error?, do you get the output but the url is empty?, or what?

Comment: @Neat didn't get output

Comment: Write your body tag as:- echo "<body style='background-image: url($background_image);background-size:100% auto;background-repeat: no-rpeat;'>";

Answer (score 0):

Use urlencode. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Like the author said: _I tried trim() and urlencode() to remove spaces but didn't work._

Comment: $new_image = str_replace(' ', '%20', $new_image);  use this

Answer (score 0):

You can replace spaces using str_replace:

```
$background_image = str_replace(' ', '', $background_image);
```

Or for all whitespace, preg_replace:

```
$background_image = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $background_image);
```

Comment: Second one is the better one

Comment: For simple 'space' removal regular expressions should not be needed @bub

Answer (score 0):

For just spaces, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_background_image = str_replace(' ', '%20', $background_image);
```